# Regex combining 2 complete lines of call data

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, txt

I am preparing a python script that simply grabs call records from a .txt log file based on a user inputted phone number.

**I need help writing a regex that captures each call log** so it can be "split" into a list.
Each log starts with the letters e.g. (L,N,S,E).
At the begging of each log that is a time stamp that starts with a "T". Example: `T                        02/25 00:00`

Records that start with (N,S,E) have a second line that need to be include. Alternatively, (L) records do not, but they  do have an empty space below which could be included.

**Essentially, what I need is every record that starts with (L,N,S,E) and the line bellow it.**

*See call log sample bellow*

> ```
> T                        02/25 00:00 
> L 065 00 24329   12313   244.0.15.55 252.9.11.90 02/25 08:05 00:00:44 0000 0000 
>                                                                 
> N 066 00 23442   T000185 262.1.00.09 02/25 08:05 00:00:02 A 16630
> &       0000    0000                                      
> S 067 00 00984   T000134             02/25 08:06 00:00:02 A 61445
> &       0000    0000                                      
> S 068 00 T000002 29536               02/25 08:05 00:00:36 
> &       0000    0000   1234567890XXXXXX                   
> E 069 00 T000002 T000185             02/25 08:06 00:00:00 
> &       0000    0000   1234567890XXXXXX
> ```

For example:

> ```
> L 065 00 24329   12313   244.0.15.55 252.9.11.90 02/25 08:05 00:00:44 0000 0000
> ```

would be one match and

> ```
> N 066 00 23442   T000185 262.1.00.09 02/25 08:05 00:00:02 A 16630
> &       0000    0000
> ```

would be another,

> ```
> S 068 00 T000002 29536               02/25 08:05 00:00:36 
> &       0000    0000   1234567890XXXXXX
> ```

would be another, and so on...

My regex knowledge is limited, but this is what I have come up with so far.

```
N(.*)\n(.*)
```

This selects the first and second line of each record that starts with "N", but it puts them in separate groups. Any direction is appreciated.

Comment: Put them in one group? `N(.*\n.*)` or only match the second line if it also does not start with L N S or E `^[LNSE]( .*\n(?![LNSE] ).*)` https://regex101.com/r/4t49CK/1

Comment: Does the entire log file only contain logs beginning with L, N, S or E ?

Comment: @Thefourthbird, the latter. Only match if it does not start with those letters.

Comment: @Cubix48, there is one exception at the head of each log file. T which indicates time. Example: "T                        02/25 00:00"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match any of those 4 characters, you can use a character class `[LNSE]` followed by a space and the rest of the line.

Then in the same capture group use an optional part to match a newline and the rest of the line if it does not start with any of those characters.

This allows for also matching only a single line.

```
^[LNSE] (.*(?:\n(?![LNSE] ).*)?)
```

- `^` Start of string
- `[LNSE]`  Match any of the listed characters and a space
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `.*` match the rest of the line
  - `(?:` Non capture group

    - `\n(?![LNSE] ).*` Match a newline and the rest of the line if it does not start with any of the listed characters using a negative lookahead
  - `)?` Close the non capture group and make it optional
- `)` Close the non capture group

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8I7wWZ/1) and a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/HMms2A).

- If you want to match 0 or more following lines, you [can change](https://regex101.com/r/g4VsJh/1) the `?` to `*` for zero or more repetitions.
- If you want to match the whole line including the leading characters, you can omit the capture group and just get [the match](https://regex101.com/r/Tr4vSX/1).

For example, getting the capture group 1 value using re.findall while reading the whole file:

```
import re

with open('file.log', 'r') as file:
    regex = r"^[LNSE] (.*(?:\n(?![LNSE] ).*)*)"
    print(re.findall(regex, file.read(), re.MULTILINE))
```

Comment: The demo looks great, and I believe this answers my question the way I asked it. although when using the re statement in my script with a split() function it doesn't delineate each group into separate list values. instead, the entirety of the content in the log is entered into one list item. i.e. I have a list with a single large value. Any thoughts on this? Thanks!

Comment: @That is because you should use a match and get the capture group value, see https://ideone.com/HMms2A

Comment: I see, got it working, thanks. Last question, is there a way to preserve the letters in the front? Including the LNSE letters in the match?

Comment: @RyanBobo But of course, you can omit the capture group `^[LNSE] .*(?:\n(?![LNSE] ).*)?` see https://regex101.com/r/Tr4vSX/1

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to do so without regex:

```
data = []
with open('file.log', 'r') as f:
    next(f)
    for line in f:
        if line[0] in ("L", "N", "S", "E"):
            data.append(line)
        else:
            data[-1] += line
print(data)
```

- `next(f)` is used to skip the first line (`T 02/25 00:00`).

---

Assuming that all logs are two lines long, one can also use a list comprehension:

```
with open('file.log', 'r') as f:
    next(f)
    lines = f.readlines()
    data = [''.join(lines[i:i+2]) for i in range(0, len(lines), 2)]
print(data)
```

Each line is stored in a list `lines` (except the first line, which has been skipped). The list comprehension then joins elements of the list two by two.

The same if the log file is stored in a variable:

```
lines = text.split("\n")[1:]  # [-1:] to skip the first line
data = [''.join(lines[i:i+2]) for i in range(0, len(lines), 2)]
print(data)
```

---

**Output:**

```
[
    'L 065 00 24329   12313   244.0.15.55 252.9.11.90 02/25 08:05 00:00:44 0000 0000\n                                                                \n', 
    'N 066 00 23442   T000185 262.1.00.09 02/25 08:05 00:00:02 A 16630\n&       0000    0000                                      \n', 
    'S 067 00 00984   T000134             02/25 08:06 00:00:02 A 61445\n&       0000    0000                                      \n', 
    'S 068 00 T000002 29536               02/25 08:05 00:00:36 \n&       0000    0000   1234567890XXXXXX                   \n', 
    'E 069 00 T000002 T000185             02/25 08:06 00:00:00 \n&       0000    0000   1234567890XXXXXX'
]
```